# How HashSet of collection framework identifies duplicate objects? How Hashcode and equals work with custom objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I was looking at some code and found one program where they have extended HashSet class of collection. They have created custom employee objects and inserted into Set without implementing Comparable or Comparator. They implemented logic to identify duplicate employee object so if object is already there They can perform update operation if object is not present they can do insert operation. I was trying to understand how set will identify duplicate object without implementiong Comparable or Comparator interface.

I have tried same and also tried to override Hashcode and equals method to understand how Set comparing objects. One thing I have found that while I am adding same object to set its generating same Hashcode. But its not calling equals method I have overrided.

```
class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;

    Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("HashCode : " + super.hashCode());
    return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Equals : " + super.equals(o));
    return super.equals(o);
    }
}

class LimitedHashSet extends HashSet<Employee> {
    public boolean add(Employee e) {
        if(!super.add(e)){
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
}
public class ExtendingHashSet {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Employee e0 = new Employee(1,"A");
    Employee e1 = new Employee(2,"B");

    LimitedHashSet obj = new LimitedHashSet();

    System.out.println("Element added ? " + obj.add(e0) + "\n");
    System.out.println("Element added ? " + obj.add(e1) + "\n");
    System.out.println("Element added ? " + obj.add(e0) + "\n");
}
}
```

Hashcode is use to calculate bucket and equals method identifies its equals or not. So how its working here. Please check output below.

Output:

HashCode : 914424520
Element added ? true

HashCode : 110718392
Element added ? true

HashCode : 914424520
Element added ? false

Comment: @AndyTurner: The code is calling `obj.add(e0)` in the last line, not `obj.add(e3)`.

Comment: @Aks1316 did you mean to add `e3` rather than `e0` on the second time?

Comment: Also: what do you think overriding `add` in `LimitedHashSet` does? It looks like it is equivalent to just calling `return super.add(e);`.

Comment: @AndyTurner No adding e0 again. If I am adding e3 it will return true and add e3 to set without any issue. But If I am trying to add e0 again its not adding it in set and providing me result false as shown in output.

Comment: @AndyTurner, For add in LimitedHashSet, its just overriding add method of HashSet. I am also not finding any specific logic for that. But it's written in same way 
I have found that's why I keep it same way.

Comment: i believe  @Aks1316 you are asking something and your code show something where both are different, stick to one point and edit the code accordingly

Comment: @Deadpool: I have edited my question and removed e3 and e2. Is it clear now? My question is simple. Without implementing Comparatble or comparator how HashSet identifies I am inserting e0 again? HashSet is not calling equals method still able to find duplicate object

Comment: `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`, where the **key** into the map is `Employee.hashCode()`.  So putting another `Employee` object with the same attribute values into the set generates the same hash code, and replaces the existing object in the backing map.  The false from earlier discussion meant the key value (the hash code) already existed.  `Employee.equals()` is not used to determine the **key** value in the backing map.

Comment: @AndrewS that's misleading on several levels.  The key is an `Employee`, not its `hashCode`.  Employee objects with the same attribute values currently have different hash codes, given the implementation from above.

Comment: @Aks1316 it identifies that you're inserting `e0` again by using `==` to check if the keys are reference-equal.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, there *is no magic.*

`HashSet` and all JDK hash-based collections blindly use the implementations of `hashCode` and `equals` definitions for your objects to determine if objects are the same or not.  They just call the `hashCode` and `equals` methods, and however those work, that's what the hash collections use.

Part of the point of the use of the `hashCode` method -- part of the point of hash-based data structures in the first place -- is to make it *unlikely* that the hash-based collection even has to bother calling the `equals` method to check if two objects are the same.  If the hashes aren't the same, then the objects are definitely not equal.  So it *would* call the `equals` method you have overridden if it needed to, but in your code, it doesn't need to bother calling `equals`.  Furthermore, it also checks reference equality before calling the `equals` methods, because if two objects are `==` then they are definitely `.equals` to each other.

Currently, you are adding `e0` twice.  By reference equality, `e0 == e0`, so it doesn't bother calling `.equals` -- it just finds the matching entry, checks that they're reference-equal, and keeps the existing entry without adding a new element.  This is the correct behavior, by the way, since `e0` is a duplicate of itself.

Comment: @AndyTurner: not sure what you mean.  Whether or not it's what the doc says, it's what the JDK implementation does, because it assumes your implementation is contract-compliant, and it's why the OP's program doesn't print "Equals: ..."